# .htaccess REQUEST_URI not work well

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try this rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dr/he
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} temp.il.gl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.il.gl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but when I try also temp.il.gl/dr/he/ and also http://temp.il.gl/dr/

They both go to m.il.gl
I try it at .htaccess tester and this work, but when insert it in my .htaccess is not work.
Thanks.

EDITED:
I have this lines also:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

EDITED:
I add the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)index.php
```

before:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.il.gl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And now is work.
Thanks to you
Yoni

Comment: Are there any rewrite rules in the virtual host?

Comment: I don't know? how can I check it.

Comment: Do you have access to httpd.conf?

Comment: The second one `http://temp.il.gl/dr/` is expected. The first one might be cached from an earlier 301 redirect.

Comment: @OlafDietsche when I can see it work?

Comment: @user1425790 Sorry, I don't understand that question. What do you mean?

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)index.php
    I add this line.
Hope is work.
Check it, and return

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This rule says if the requested path does NOT start with `/dr/he`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dr/he
```

AND the host answering the request is temp.il.gl

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} temp.il.gl
```

The redirect ALL traffic to m.il.gl permanently.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.il.gl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

1. If this is not intended, or if this is not the behavior you're experiencing check the `/dr/he` directory for a file that also contains a redirect.
2. Check the virtual host to see if there is possibly a conflicting `mod_rewrite` declaration.
3. Maybe there is another line in `.htaccess` that is performing the transfer?
4. If they're both on the same server maybe it's a DNS issue with the way the server is configured. (If the server is configured to answer for both.)
5. Browsers typically cache 301 redirects, so if you accidentally redirected all traffic at one point you may need to flush your browser cache to have it stop redirecting for the "/dr/he" folder.

Comment: 3. Yes, you right.    
This is the line:   
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]       
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico

Comment: Yes, you right. This is the line: 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

Comment: So that rule says anything that's not a real file, and not a real directory and is not favicon.ico gets redirected back to index.php. So if your folders don't contain an index.php. Once something goes to index.php then it qualifies for your other rule and is redirected to the other site.